Hörmander's proof of Beurling's uncertainty principle and the application of Phragmén-Lindelöf
I am trying to understand the proof in the following paper.
https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1007%2FBF02384339
where it is proven that if
$$\int \int_{R^2}|f(x)\hat{f}(y)|e^{|xy|}dxdy < \infty$$
then $f=0$
I understood the first part, where we came to the conclusion that for
$$\hat{M}(y)=\int|f(x)|e^{|xy|}dx, \quad M(x)=\int|\hat{f}(y)|e^{|xy|}dy$$
there is an entire continuation of $f$ and $\hat{f}$, which satisifies
$$|f(z)|\leq M(Im(z)), \quad |\hat{f}(z)|\leq \hat{M}(Im(z))$$
i also get that
$$F(\zeta)=\int_0^\zeta f(z)f(iz)dz$$
is bounded on the real and imaginary axes
but I don't understand how it follows from the Phragmén-Lindelöf theorem, that if we had that for every $c>0$
$$\lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} M(x)e^{-cx^2/2}=0$$
then f would be bounded, and hence equal to 0.
edit:
My current idea is, that there is no quick proof to show the case where $M$ and thus also $f$ have this rate of decay. The author just first assumes, that the function is of order $\geq 2$ to show that it is actually of order exactly 2. The rest of the argument then is applied to the case were the function is of order $\leq 2$, thus also proving the case previously ruled out.
However, he first writes "f is a bounded function, hence equal to 0." Whereas below he proves that, $F$ is bounded and thus $f=0$.
Thus I am not quite sure if my argument is correct or if there is actually a way to apply Phragmén-Lindelöf directly to $f$ at that point.
